# Why isn't my css applying?

Tags: html, css

I tried using different editors and IDEs (netbeans and visual studio code) along with different browsers (firefox developers edition), yet, I can't seem to get the css sheet to apply to the main html file.
The style sheet editor is saying that there is no style sheet attached to the html file
Here's the html file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>The Animal Game</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8"/>
        <link href="animalgame.css" type="text/css" rel="stylsheet" />
        <script src="animalgame.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <h1>The Animal Game</h1>
        <p>Think of an animal, then let me guess it!</p>
        <div id="container">
            <fieldset>
                <legend>Questions</legend>
                <p id="questions"></p>
            </fieldset>
            <fieldset id="answer">
                <legend>Answer</legend>
                <button id="yes">Yes</button>
                <button id="no" >No</button>
            </fieldset>
        </div>

    </body>
</html>
```

CSS style sheet:

```
body {
    font: 12pt "Century Gothic", "Helvetica", "Arial", sans-serif;
}

button {
    font-size: 20pt;
    font-weight: bold;
    margin: 15px auto;

}
#container{
    margin: auto;
    width: 520px;
}
fieldset {
    background-color: #F0F0F0;
    float: left;
    height: 150px;
    margin-right: 15px;
    text-align: center;

}
h1, p {
    text-align: center;
}
#questions {
    font-size: 16pt;
    text-align: center;
    width: 300px;
}
```

EDIT: problem solved! There was a typo. Thank you for all hints

Comment: Do you have any errors in your console?

Comment: @George no error is displayed

Comment: Are both .html and .css files in the same folder?

Comment: Ideas for you!  1.  bring up fiddler, clear your cache, and refresh.  Make sure the css file is being read and not a 404 due to capitalization issue or whatnot.  2.  Dump the CSS into the file itself, and make sure it's working the way you expect.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have a typo in `rel="stylsheet"` it should be `stylesheet`

Comment: You could avoid such simple typos by using some library, or plugin in your favorite IDE that helps you with the HTML Boiler Plate code; SublimeText HTML BoilerPlate, for example. Save yourself the pain!

Comment: @Program-Me-Rev I'll dig that up! I hope visual studio code offers such libraries